# Return statement in IF LET vs GUARD LET

Tags: ios, swift3

Look at the following two scenarios with same code:

**Using IF LET:**

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?){
    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
        for service in peripheral.services!
        {
            print("discovered service is ::::",service)
        }
}
```

**Using GUARD LET:**

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?){
        guard let _ = error else{
            for service in peripheral.services!
            {
                print("discovered service is ::::",service)
            }
        return
       }
    }
```

Both of them are using `return statement` and both of them serve the same purpose then **what are the differences and which one is better?**

*EDITS:-*

**Problem is for general statement it's fine to use any of them but when we have error to handle which one is best to use ?**

Comment: This is a weird function, passing in a error like that. Because of this, it's not well suited to this sort of comparison.

Comment: @Shubham Mishra one more + point with guard let is , it also provide use of break,and main purpose is to keep code clean and well readable.

Comment: Problem is for general statement it's fine but when we have error to handle what is best to use ?

Comment: @ShubhamMishra its your choice which you want . Before guard let was introduced we used if let. But that made code look complex ,lots of nesting and extra use of {}. This was overcome by guard let.Use case is same to handle nil value crash,but also is good to keep code clean and understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, None of them is properly implemented.

- In `peripheral.services!` if `services` will be nil, it will crash.
- Return statement - There is no necessity of return in both, you can just remove it from `if-let` and everything will work fine
- The benefit of `guard` over `if-let` is it reduces `if-else` brackets resulting more **readable code**
- You use `guard` if you care about value of variable outside the block scope, think about `if-let` you can only use unwrapped variable inside block only.
- Use `if-let` for small number of variables unwrapping and value of unwrapped variable not required outside block scope
- Use `guard-else` for using unwrapped variables outside block scope
- If you are going to use `error` object outside the block scope(main use of guard block) then go with `guard-else` otherwise go with `if-let`.

Comment: if error is not nil then only service will be nil, and error checking is already done

Comment: It is not always the case, because `services` is optional you should unwrap it with `if-let` or `guard-else`

Comment: Got it but Problem is for general statement it's fine but when we have error to handle which one is best to use ?

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `guard` in this scenario makes your intention clearer—you only want the function to execute if there is no error.

What I like best about `guard` is that it keeps you from deeply nesting `if` brackets which makes the code more readable. In your code, to make this happen, you would, however, put it in a format like this:

```
guard error != nil else { return }
... // continue with regular code
```

Apart from that `guard` and `if` yield the same result—it mostly is a matter of taste.

Comment: Problem is for general statement it's fine but when we have error to handle what is best to use ?

Answer (score 2):

Guard statements are very good for dealing with "pyramids of doom". The way I'm using it is for example keyboard notification:

```
func keyboardWillShowSelector(notification:NSNotification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
        let height = keyboardFrame.size.height
        keyboardWillShow(withHeight: height)
}
```

Without guard statement it will have another intent and the code will not be so clean:

```
func keyboardWillShowSelector(notification:NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
            keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
            let height = keyboardFrame.size.height
            keyboardWillShow(withHeight: height)
        }
}
```

Another great example is validation:

```
private func errorFromInputValidation(name: String, email: String, password1: String, password2: String) -> String? {
        guard password1 != "" && password2 != "" && email != "" && name != ""  else { return Localizable.fieldsCannotBeEmpty.localized }
        guard password1 == password2 else { return Localizable.passwordsAreNotEqual.localized }
        return nil
}
```

Comment: Problem is for general statement it's fine but when we have error to handle what is best to use ?

Comment: It depends, you can implement everything with if and guard. It's only to make the code cleaner.